# Execute JavaScript async from Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

So there is this [async attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) in  that is supposed to execute JavaScript immediately rather than waiting for it to load completely.

Using this attribute in  tag within Visualforce will require at least ="", which is does not seem to be part of the standard.

The problem is that with few scripts loading, [BirthDay Picker plugin for jQuery](http://abecoffman.com/2011/jquery-birthday-picker/) always render the drop-downs dead last. It is bad user experience and I also need to add event listeners on these drop-downs.

Looking at the plugin code I cannot see any listeners that would wait for DOM loaded.

Also, looking at execution timeline, it looks that elements get rendered right after SfdcCore.js's Recalculate Style event.

Now, running JS async might not solve the problem, but I was curious to try. Any additional help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use [pass through attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) i.e. `html-async="async"`. I doubt that it is going to help with your problem though.

Comment: It actually works without html- passthrough, but still it's not exactly up to the spec. Also, realized because my event binding is executing, so chances are that platform is not really limiting execution of script (but perhaps is limiting the render of elements).